# AccountDomainSID is the same for all users accessing ASP.Net MVC site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

The site is under ApplicationPoolIdentity in IIS7.5, we are using Windows Authentication.

When running this code, AccoundDomainSID is the same for all users accessing the site, not unique.

Are there any IIS settings that need to be configured for this to work properly?

```
string SID = new WindowsIdentity(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token).Owner.Value;
```

Is there any other way to obtain AccountDomainSID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to obtain the identity associated with the application's current user off the Request object:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // foo is just a <DIV ID="foo" runat="server"/>
        foo.InnerHtml += Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name  + "<br/>";
        foo.InnerHtml += Request.LogonUserIdentity.User.Value+"<br/>";

   }
}
```